# Unable to install ccmake

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, cmake

[Preface: I have seen similar questions, but that did not help me and so this new question. To explain in more detail, I followed the steps in [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies), without rectifying the problem]

I am trying to install `ccmake`.

However, I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake-curses-gui : Depends: cmake (= 2.8.7-0ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get -f install`, but it did not help.

I am unable to find broken packages either.

Comment: Yes, I followed that.

Comment: It did not sort out my problem and hence I posted another question. :)

Comment: did u try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Yes. Still the same error occurs.
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
** something**
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cmake-curses-gui : Depends: cmake (= 2.8.7-0ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
$

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`, `apt-cache policy cmake-curses-gui cmake` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`

Comment: I actually solved the problem. Since it is marked as duplicate, I cannot answer the question.

I remove cmake and cmake-data, reinstalled them and then installed ccmkake. Worked perfect! I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

cmake-curses-gui depends on cmake (= 2.8.7-0ubuntu4) for a precise installation.

If you're unable to install this particular version it means that you installed a different version on your system.

Try first to uninstall cmake:

```
sudo apt-get remove cmake
```

And install again cmake-curses-gui:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake-curses-gui
```

If it doesn't work check if you're not pulling a different version of cmake from a ppa.

Comment: Same error.
How do I confirm that I am not pulling a different version of cmake from a ppa?

Comment: Do `apt-cache policy cmake`.

Comment: Installed: 2.8.7-0ubuntu4
  Candidate: 2.8.7-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 2.8.7-0ubuntu4 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: I had a similar issue on Ubuntu 22. I had also to remove cmake-data, only cmake was not sufficient.